# How to launch a mono process with arguments from C# mono on Linux

Tags: c#, ubuntu, mono

In ubuntu, from one application (C# running on Mono), I am trying to launch a 2nd C# Mono application and pass some arguments.

I do so like this:

```
            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.FileName = "Mono";
            p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = a_working_dir;
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = "anExe.exe arg1 arg2 arg3";
            p.Start();
```

At runtime I get an error saying:

```
xdg-open: unexpected argument 'arg1 arg2 arg3'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `xdc-open` is being used?... Is the `mono` binary in your path? otherwise supply the fullpath to it (ie. `/usr/local/bin/mono`) and it should be `mono` (all lowercase).

Comment: it appears the xdc-open is being used, not by my design. mono is not in my path - is that the problem?

Comment: Assign the full path of mono to `p.StartInfo.FileName`